# Count text cells based on other cell's value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with data, I want to count text cells based on other cell's value. For example

```
    A       B         C
    name1    yes     Pay
    name2    no      pay
    name7    no
    name1    yes

Total = 2
```

I want to count cell A when Cell C is empty. I means only count Cell A text values when there is nothing entered in cell C.

I tried this formula `=count(C:C, "", A:A, "<> ")` but it counts empty rows of Cell A also.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple conditions can be specified with [`countifs`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en). For example,

```
=countifs(A:A, "<>", C:C, "")
```

says to count a row only if the entry in A column is nonempty and the entry in C column is empty.